# How random is AdamOptimizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose:

1. I feed the data in the same order to 10 AdamOptimizer.
2. All AdamOptimizer tries to minimize the same objective function.
3. The initial values for the variables are different for the 10 AdamOptimizer
4. Some of the variables (let call them set b) should have no effect on the minimal value of the objective function. But I don't know which variables are in set b before the minimization.
5. The objective function is deterministic.

Would the variables in set b have different values for the 10 minimization?

I am trying to run the 10 minimization concurrently on a GPU.
The training data is large.

Comment: try it? measure it?

Comment: Have you tried doing it yourself? It seems like your question is easily answerable if you try it out yourself. Currently, it looks like we either have to try it out for ourselves then tell you the results or, *if one knows a lot about the Adam Optimizer*, reply based off of knowledge and experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How random is the Adam optimizer?

*The randomness in your result `y` is not something Adam brings for the fixed values of hyper-parameters. It is based on parameters `W` and biases `b` TensorFlow fills in in respect to `np.random.seed(0)` or `tf.set_random_seed(0)`.*

As described in [Adam](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980.pdf), it is RMSProp combined with Gradient Descent with momentum.

If you check out the [arguments](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam):

- lr: float >= 0. Learning rate.
- beta_1: float, 0 < beta < 1. Generally close to 1.
- beta_2: float, 0 < beta < 1. Generally close to 1.
- epsilon: float >= 0. Fuzz factor. If None, defaults to K.epsilon().
- decay: float >= 0. Learning rate decay over each update.
- amsgrad: boolean. Whether to apply the AMSGrad variant of this algorithm from the paper "On the Convergence of Adam and Beyond".

There are quite a few, and by default:

```
__init__(
    lr=0.001,
    beta_1=0.9,
    beta_2=0.999,
    epsilon=None,
    decay=0.0,
    amsgrad=False, **kwargs
)
```

For the fixed set of the default hyper-parameters the results will be the same.

Comment: Adding white noise to either the training data or the variables would make the variables in set b wander randomly. The problem is that I cannot predict the strength of the white noise at start of the minimization. Does Adam already adds white noise with adaptive strength to the training data?

Comment: No but check the impact of the parameter [epsilon](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342892/what-is-the-meaning-of-fuzz-factor), this affects the calculation.